# why Undefined problem in alertbox javascript occur when i click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

I am trying this code  and i also try other method but still this problem occur so remember vs code is my editor.

```
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="name" />
    <button onclick="fun()">click me</button>
    <script>
      function fun() {
        var fir = Number(document.getElementById("name").Value);
        alert(fir);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: it is `value` not `Value` : `var fir = Number(document.getElementById("name").value);`

Comment: i also try value

Comment: tried same code changing `Value` to `value` it worked : [link here to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy6cvns2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `value` as suggested in the comment as following,

```html
 <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="name" />
    <button onclick="fun()">click me</button>
    <script>
      function fun() {
        var fir = Number(document.getElementById("name").value);
        alert(fir);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```